# `@import` doesn't include styles even url is 100% correct

Tags: css

I try to include css style.

```
@import url("http://mydomain.com/theme/css/reset.css")
```

but styles have not been included

When I open http://mydomain.com/theme/css/reset.css in the browser all is loaded and I can see css rules. What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you get a console error in the developer tools?

Comment: It would help if you could create a public demo that shows the problem; with this little to go on, the best anyone can do is keep guessing and asking you to try things, which doesn't fit well with the format of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@import` requires a semicolon:

```
@import url("http://mydomain.com/theme/css/reset.css");
```

From MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

> @import url;
>   or
>   @import url list-of-media-queries;
>
> where :
>
> url Is a  or a  representing the location of the resource
>   to import. The url may be an absolute or relative url. Note that the
>   url needn't actually specify a file; it can just specify the package
>   name and part, and the appropriate file will be chosen automatically
>   (eg. chrome://communicator/skin/). See here for more information.
>
> list-of-media-queries Is a comma-separated list of media queries
>   conditioning the application of the css rules defined in the linked
>   url. If the browser doesn't support any of these media types, it won't
>   even load the linked resource.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy awesome. If I fully answered your question, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: sure, couldn't do that before, system said I can accept answer in 30 minutes